# Open New view on iPad, and close existing view. 

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view (View1, assigned to View1Controller) opened on my iPad. How can I get it to open View2 (View2Controller) and close itself... I am sure it's dead simple but I'm managing popovers and can't find something so simple. An animated transition would be preferable if possible.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of one way you can accomplish this.

Let's assume you have properties in your AppDelegate called `viewController1` and `viewController2` (these should be `nonatomic, retain` to make memory management easier).

When you want to switch from `viewController1` to `viewController2` you need to remove to do the following

```
// Remove the old view
[self.viewController1.view removeFromSuperView];
// Release it's controller (just to economize on memory)
self.viewController1.view = nil;
if(self.viewController2 == nil)
{
    // Load the new controller from it's NIB/XIB
    ViewController2* vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] 
                                 initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" 
                                 bundle:nil];
    // Assign it to property & release to keep memory management clean
    self.viewController2 = vc2;
    [vc2 release];
}
// Add the new view controller to the window
[self.window addSubview:vc2];
```

One of the easiest ways to inform the AppDelegate to switch views is to use the notification center.

Since you are retaining the view controllers in properties do not forget to release them in your `dealloc`.
Hope this helps you out.

Comment: What if my views were created without nibs and instead created by code.

Comment: Just replace the initWithNib with however you are creating the `ViewController1` and `ViewController2` in your question. (Though even if the views are created in code you should just be able to pass `nil` for `initWithNibName` that will cause your controller's `loadView` to be called which is where you should be creating programmatic views).